# Need an event to fire when a Form in an MDI container closes?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mdi

I have a Multi Document Interface control with some Forms nested inside of it. I need an event to fire when one of those forms are closed. How may I bind such an event?

If it matters, the code I need to run accesses a global class called data, which has a public static property called Windows, which is accessed like so:

```
data.Windows -= 1;
```

Comment: I am not sure I can understand your problem, what is wrong with `FormClosing` event?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538204/mdi-form-detecting-with-a-child-form-is-added-or-removed

Comment: Just add this to your form `protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("goodbye cruel world"); }`

Comment: OnClosing is obsolete, use OnFormClosing.

Comment: look at the properties window in vs which lists all events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed as L.B says: Create an override in the form class. It can be placed anywhere in the class

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) 
  data.Windows = -1; //assuming this variable still exists at that time
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
private void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //form is new mdi child
    Form form = this.MdiChildren.Last();
    form.FormClosed += SenderForm_Close;
}

private void SenderForm_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //form is new closed mdi child
    Form form = sender as Form;
}
```