# Layout remaining forms when a form closes

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a MdiParent that opens multiple instances of a form as its MdiChildren.  When each form is opened, I call `this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);` to lay out all forms.

What I want to do is do the same thing for when a form closes but I can't do it in the MdiChildren's FormClosing or FormClosed event handlers because it still includes the closed form when laying out the forms (even though it's not shown)

Any ideas on how to get this accomplished, perhaps in the MdiParent?

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538204/mdi-form-detecting-with-a-child-form-is-added-or-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the children in the MdiParent form, and then wire up a `Disposed` handler:

```
private List<Form> _childForms = new List<Form>();

protected override void OnMdiChildActivate(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMdiChildActivate(e);

    Form f = ActiveMdiChild;
    if (f == null)
        return;
    else
    {
        if (!_childForms.Contains(f))
        {
            _childForms.Add(f);
            f.Disposed += new EventHandler(childForm_Disposed);
        }
    }
}

private void childForm_Disposed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _childForms.Remove((Form)sender);
    this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could tie a child form's event to a handler in the parent form.

Comment: @user1199931 Once you have the reference to the form, you can do lots of things with it.

Answer (score 1):

I like @DonBoitnott's answer.  If you wanted to stick with the FormClosed() event, however, then simply Dispose() of the form before calling LayoutMdi():

```
    void frm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm = (Form)sender;
        // ... possibly do something with "frm" BEFORE it's disposed of ...
        frm.Dispose();

        this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
    }
```